# Unable to deleteing folders

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, pyrocms

From the admin, I am able to create new folders from the browser but unable to delete the created folders.

`http://localhost/<project>/admin/files` .

However the delete does not work. When I right-click over the folders and click on delete, nothing happens. How do I delete them ?

[image]

Comment: Turn on debug & check your php error_log. What do you get?

Comment: How do I do it ? I have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the root index.php.

Comment: Depending on where your log files are, there should be a log file, this is defined in the php.ini.

Comment: Ok, now it seems to work after empting the folder. Weird. I had tried that a number of times and it hadn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check your permissions in security and see if only system is listed. If so recreate the folder with permissions set as everyone with R/W/E.